Relationship between quotient CW-complexes after attaching cells
I have been trying to prove the following simple-looking result which I require for some work in low-dimensional topology. I expect it is likely true and in a textbook somewhere so any reference or proof would be much appreciated, but it is possible my guess is off so any direction towards a counterexample would of course be useful as well.
From now we assume all CW-complexes to have a single $0$-cell.
Given a CW-pair $(Y,X)$, we form $X’$ by gluing some amount of new cells to $X$ (where these new cells are arbitrary and not cells of $Y$). We denote by $Y'$ the result of gluing in these same cells to $Y$ by gluing them into the subcomplex $X\subset Y$. We ensure in doing this that the new cells do not intersect $Y$ outside of this gluing into $X\subset Y$. The question is do we have that $Y/X$ is homeomorphic to $Y'/X'$?
Some notes so far: the cells of $Y/X$ can be identified with those of $Y-X$ and a $0$-cell, and likewise for $Y'/X'$, so in particular these quotient spaces have the same cells (in the sense that there is a natural identification between the cells of each space). Hence it suffices to check that the attaching maps are the same through this identification. I think I can prove the result for when $X$ and $Y$ are 2-complexes, but I am interested as to whether it is true in some higher dimensions as well.

I don’t understand the question. Are the cells you are gluing to X already part of Y? What does  “gluing in these same cells to $X\subset Y$ such that they do not intersect $Y$ outside of $X$” mean, precisely? [For those voting to close, could we please give the OP a chance to clarify what he’s asking?]

Apologies for the confusion, will edit the question to make it more clear. The idea is we take $Y$ and then glue in the cells we glued to $X$ (when we made X’) to the subcomplex $X\subset Y$. Whilst doing this we ensure that the new cells glued onto $Y$ only intersect $Y$ at the points of $X\subset Y$ where we define the original gluing.

I recommend the first appendix of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book for this kind of general topology issues.

@DanRamras to answer you first question the cells we attach to $X$ to get $X’$ are arbitrary and not related to $Y$ in any way, although I appreciate the way I wrote it could have seemed to imply this.

@FernandoMuro Thanks for the recommendation. I have checked Hatcher for this and can’t seem to find a statement related to this. However I am trying to use these basic results to get to the bottom of my issue.

@WilliamThomas I think that Proposition A.2 in the aforementioned book by Hatcher should solve your problem.

@FernandoMuro Thanks, I’ll have a look into applying this, was originally trying to prove it inductively on the $n$-skeleton but will try working through this direction.

If I understand the question correctly, you have a CW complex $Y'$ which is the union of two subcomplexes $Y$ and $X'$ whose intersection is the subcomplex $X$.  We can first collapse $X$ to a point to get $Y'/X$ as the wedge sum $Y/X \vee X'/X$. Then when $X'/X$ is collapsed to a point one gets $Y/X$. This two-stage collapsing is equivalent to the forming the single collapse $Y'/X'$.  So $Y'/X' = Y/X$.
To check that there is no problem with the point-set topology, one can compare the characteristic maps for $Y'/X'$ and $Y/X$, which are really the same maps.
